# Understanding a proof about equivalence of norms in metric spaces.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

**Theorem: $||.||$ and $||.||'$ norms in the vector space $E$ are equivalent $\iff \exists A,B>0 $  st.  $A||x|| \leq ||x||' \leq B||x||$.**

Proof: $I:(E,||.||) \to (E,||.||')$ is linear.
Then $I:(E,||.||) \to (E,||.||')$ is continuous $\iff \exists B>0 $ st. $||x||' \leq B||x|| \forall x \in E$.

My problem is seeing why $I:(E,||.||) \to (E,||.||')$ is linear. How can I verify this? Linearity is defined by these equalities: $I(x+y) = I(x) + I(y)$ and $I(ax) = aI(x)$. I don't quite see where the norm enters here...

The rest of the theorem I understood because of a previous proposition regarding linear transformations, continuity, and existence of $B$.

Comment: You are asking why the identity function on a vector space is linear?

Comment: Oh. Yes, I was, but now I see how obvious it is. $I(x+y) = x+y = I(x) + I(y)$, $I(ax) = ax = aI(x)$

Comment: My confusion was because of the validity of this with norms but not with metrics, but the hypothesis of normed spaces was used in the theorem I mentioned. Thanks.